# automate typing in r console

Tags: r, string, function, console

Consider the following function from a package called `spotifyr`:

```
get_artist_audio_features(artist_name=)
```

The function returns a data frame with one observation for every game a team has played and team-level stats for each game, which it pulls from Spotify's API. When I type `"Drake"` in the team_name argument...

`team1 <- get_artist_audio_features(artist_name="Drake")`

the following message appears in my console:

```
We found the following artists on Spotify matching "Drake":

    Drake
    Nick Drake
    Drake White
    Drake Bell
    Christopher Drake
    Drake Chisholm
    Seth Drake
    Drizzy Dizzy Drake
    Ludwig Von Drake
    Eleni Drake
    Julius Drake
    Cordell Drake
    LakeSide Drake
    Alfred Drake
    Molly Drake
    Nathan Drake
    Gabrielle Drake
    Pete Drake

Please type the name of the artist you would like:
```

I have to type `Drake` (with no quotes) into the console again to complete the function call and store it in my `artist1` data frame - even though I provided R with a perfect match on the artist name I wanted data for during my first call.

Unfortunately, **this becomes a problem for automation.** I want to write a function that loops over a vector of artist names called `artists` and stores the game-level attributes from Spotify as `artist[i]` data frames. Alas, `get_artist_audio_features()` requires I type each team name into the console before accessing the API and storing the requested data. Again, each item in my vector matches the Spotify name I want to call *perfectly* - so if I could use these strings as the response to the question in the console, I'd be all set.

But `print(artists[i])`, `return(artists[i])`, or even `artists[i]` don't just return the string in the console - they also include the syntax used to create the string. Consider the WANT vs HAVE responses below:

WANT

```
Please type the name of the artist you would like:
Drake
```

HAVE

```
Please type the name of the artist you would like:
artists[i] #this returns "Drake" but the function doesn't see it that way
Error in get_artist_audio_features('Drake') : invalid id (400)
```

In short: is there a way to automate typed responses to a function's request in the console? Using my example above, is it possible to pull the string `Drake` from a vector and type it into the console when prompted, without adding the syntax associated with this string print?

Comment: It highly depends on the function you're calling.  Using a hypothetical function here doesn't really allow you to have a minimal reproducible example either.

Comment: Thank you - I edited my answer so the problem is reproducible. The function comes from a package called spotifyr

Comment: You need to give some actual code for the function (of the problematic part, at least) for your example to be reproducible.

Comment: You could just edit the code directly.  But a bug report should be made.  You should be able to specify that you're input an exact match.

Comment: @alistaire - the problem is that anything in the RScript that invokes the name "Drake" will throw an error, because running it will put the object's name into the console before returning "Drake." The function I use is irrelevant to the problem I describe. See my "HAVE" syntax as an example.